# CSS border-radius:20px

Tags: css

I want to set border-radius to div like that.Blur div radius appears like that. How can i fix it ? 
Thanks.

```
<div class="content" style="background-image:url('img/2.jpg');"><br>
<div class="caption"><br>
<div class="blur">/div> <br>
<h1>Click/h1><br>
</div> <br>
</div><br>
```

[image-preview here](http://postimg.org/image/a8u47dy23/) 
(edited)

[CodePen Example here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uwqoy)

```
.content
{
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 20px solid #25a9e6;
}
.caption
{
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;<br>
    -webkit-transition: all 0.20s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.20s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.20s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.20s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.20s ease-in-out;
    height:100%;
}
.blur
{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    /*background-color: rgba(7, 194, 209, 0.75);*/
    width: 210px;
    height: 210px;
    z-index: 5;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for help on formatting your question.

Comment: image and codepen are somehow alike, what is your question ?

Comment: My blur div radius appears.I edited image-preview link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add **.imageContent** class:

```
border-radius: 50px;
```

but it's temporary solution too...

Answer (score 0):

you could use less marking and dispatch border drawing to both elements to keep the curve and even draw a little more details.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ksuzK

```
div:hover h1
{
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  color:white;
}

.imageContent, h1
{
  width: 210px;
  height: 210px;    
  border-radius: 20px;

}
.imageContent {
  overflow: hidden;
  border:10px solid #25A9E6;
  padding:10px;
  background:#25A9E6;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 1px gray,
    1px 1px 3px black,
    -1px -1px 3px gray;;
  box-sizing:border-box; 
  background-image:url('http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature');
  background-size: cover;
  background-clip:padding-box;
}
h1 {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 20px #25A9E6,
    inset 1px 1px 1px black,
    inset -1px -1px 1px white;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:160px;
  color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

```
<div class="imageContent" >
  <h1>Click</h1>
</div>
```